# Spring Boot 2 Actuator endpoints return 405 on GET request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am configuring spring Boot actuator but the /actuator and /health endpoints return a 405 in each GET request.

I opened up the entire security mechanism but it's not working:

```
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,beans,env
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoint.beans.cache.time-to-live=10s
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST
```

I added the following config

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health", "/actuator").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    super.configure(http);
}
```

}

So, I followed the tutorial and it seems pretty simple, I don't see why I get this 405 on the default GET request. When I call the endpoint with cURL:

```
 curl http://localhost:8080/sm-integration/health -v --> 405
 curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/sm-integration/health -v --> 400
```

I don't understand the 400 Bad Request when doing a POST. The docs state that /health is the most basic and open endpoint and should be called as a GET call. So why the 405?

**update**
After receiving several answers, I have set the config like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health", "/actuator/**").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
}
```

I changed the call to
http://localhost:8080/sm-integration/actuator/health

But I still get the 405.

In the Tomcat access logging I do see the request has arrived.

```
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Jul/2020:16:41:06 +0000] "GET /sm-integration/actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 405 5
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Jul/2020:16:41:12 +0000] "GET /sm-integration/actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 405 5
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Jul/2020:16:41:45 +0000] "GET /sm-integration/actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 405 5
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Jul/2020:16:42:18 +0000] "GET /sm-integration/actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 405 5
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Jul/2020:16:43:04 +0000] "GET /sm-integration/actuator HTTP/1.1" 405 5
```

Comment: Unless you have moved the actuator endpoints to `/`, `/health` is the wrong path. It should be `/actuator/health`.

Comment: thanks, I also tried with the /actuator prefix, get the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK turns out I was looking in the wrong direction. Posting this answer for all who encounter the same issue.

The problem was that the project (maven module) where I introduced Actuator was a Spring WebService project. The project has a DispatcherServlet pointing to "/*". After I explicitly changed it to listen to another base url, the Actuator url was available.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean registerMessageDispatcherServlet(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    final MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*"); --> was "/*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Possible URLs:*

- Spring Boot Actuator endpoints should be accessed at **`{ip}:{port}/actuator/{endpoint}`**
- In the case of context, the path is set for an application you may access the same at **`{ip}:{port}/{context-path}/actuator/{endpoint}`**
- In case you have customized the base-path using `management.endpoints.web.base-path` you may access it at **`{ip}:{port}/{web.base-path}/{endpoint}`**

---

Remove `super.configure(http);` as it will override your configurations and change *`"/actuator"`* to *`"/actuator/**"`*

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health", "/actuator/**").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried it, I still get the 405

Comment: Hello Corn, can you please make a GET request using the postman. Also make a hit at `/actuator` and share the results

Comment: Have you defined the context path and/or custom base path for the actuators in the application

Comment: I get the same results with Postman. I have tried multiple configs, none work, I am beginning to think it might be because of some other spring config that is interfering.

Comment: I did not configure anything else than in the OP.

Comment: You may share the GitHub of the project (if possible to share) to look into the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217329/discussion-between-patel-romil-and-coen-damen).